# Kubernetes - not unique ip per pod

Tags: kubernetes

I'm building a 3 VM (CentOS 7) cluster of Kubernetes 1.3.2.
According to this kubernetes documentation page [Networking in Kubernetes](http://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/networking/): “We give every pod its own IP address” and by that there is no port collision when few pods use the same ports on the same node.
But as seen here, the pods do get the same IP addresses:

```
[root@gloom kuber-test]# kubectl get pods -o wide -l app=userloc
NAME                          READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE       IP           NODE
userloc-dep-857294609-0am9d   1/1       Running   0          27m       172.17.0.5   157.244.150.86
userloc-dep-857294609-a4538   1/1       Running   0          27m       172.17.0.7   157.244.150.96
userloc-dep-857294609-c4wzy   1/1       Running   0          6h        172.17.0.3   157.244.150.86
userloc-dep-857294609-hbl9i   1/1       Running   0          6h        172.17.0.5   157.244.150.96
userloc-dep-857294609-rpgyd   1/1       Running   0          27m       172.17.0.5   157.244.150.198
userloc-dep-857294609-tnnho   1/1       Running   0          6h        172.17.0.3   157.244.150.198
```

What do I miss?

**EDIT - 31/07/16:**
Following Sven Walter's comments, maybe the issue is that somehow the IPs which the pods had received are of the docker bridge subnet 172.17.0.0/16 (which is not distinct per node) instead of flannel’s subnets 10.x.x.x/24 (which are distinct per node).
Can this be the issue?

In case needed, here is the deployment yaml:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: userloc-dep 
spec:
  replicas: 6
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: userloc
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: userloc
        image: globe:5000/openlso/userlocation-ms:0.1 
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8081
```

Comment: As you described in your question, the ip addresses are *unique per node*.  E.g., there are three pods with address `172.17.0.5`, but they are all on different nodes.

Comment: It looks a little bit like a miss configuration of the Kubernetes cluster. The pod IPs are unique per node. AFAIK the nodes should get different subnets for their pods (eg 172.17.0.0/24, 172.17.1.0/24, 172.17.2.0/24 and so on).

Comment: @larsks IMO the IP addresses should be unique across the whole cluster. Otherwise the communication between pods wouldn't be possible.

Comment: @SvenWalter I created the cluster step-by-step following Kubernetes' documentation "Running Multi-Node Kubernetes Using Docker". How can I check if the cluster is misconfigured? I run 'kubectl get nodes' and got all 3 nodes in a 'Ready' status.

Comment: @user5396668 Sorry I don't know how to check this. We are using CoreOS with flannel. `kubectl get nodes -o json` doesn't show any useful information. I just see, that all pods on a single same node have the same `/24` subnet and these subnets differ between every node. This is basically how I think it should look like: https://github.com/coreos/flannel#theory-of-operation

Comment: This might help: https://github.com/coreos/flannel/issues/112

Comment: @SvenWalter Thanks but it is probably not my case. I checked flannel logs and they show that in each node flannel picked a distinct subnet.

Comment: @SvenWalter On a second thought it may point to the source of the problem. I'm editing my question accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: @user5396668, did you use the master.sh and worker.sh to start your cluster? Could you check the value of ${FLANNEL_SUBNET} before it being passed to docker default config here: https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-deploy/blob/master/docker-multinode/docker-bootstrap.sh#L78? Or are you using a different script?

Comment: Do you actually have a problem with the running pods? Any errors? Any collisions? If not I don't think you actually have to worry about what is shown to kubectl

Comment: @caesarxuchao, I did use master.sh and worker.sh scripts, and echoing ${FLANNEL_SUBNET} shows the right subnet. But, probably the issue is with the fact that following [docker help](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/systemd/) I had added additional docker config in /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/docker.conf that overrides the config in /usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service. I removed it and the pods got flannel’s subnet. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue occured becuase following [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/systemd/) I had added additional docker config in */etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/docker.conf* that overrides the config in */usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service*. Unfortunatelly the scripts I used to setup the cluster (master.sh and worker.sh) doesn't refer to the first file but to the second one.
Once I removed the *docker.conf* file the pods got flannel’s subnet.

Answer (score 0):

After configuring flannel, assuming you did so correctly, each node will grab a slice of the overall ip network cidr. You can figure out which cidr is assigned to which node by doing an `etcd ls -r` and looking for a key like "coreos.com". The subnet slices assigned to each node should be unique.

Once a node has a subnet, flannel assigns that cidr to flannel.0 (a vxlan device) and you need to restart docker, eg: https://github.com/coreos/flannel#docker-integration. If you failed to restart docker, or the options are wrong, or flannel isn't running on the node, or non-unique subnets are assigned to different nodes, things won't work as expected. Reply to this if you need more help debugging and we can take it from there.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the late response due a vacation. The issue was resolved; see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it can help you, I have the same problem when I had more than one network interface to fix that I defined the network interface that flannel use to communicate with other nodes.

`flanneld --iface=enp0s8`

in my case, I change that in /etc/sysconfig/flanneld

```
FLANNEL_ETCD="http://master.gary.local:2379"
FLANNEL_ETCD_KEY="/atomic.io/network"
FLANNEL_OPTIONS="--iface=enp0s8"
```

after change that obviously you need to restart docker and flanneld daemons.